# VHDL: Testbench for ASK modulator

Tags: vhdl, modulation, rtl, digital-modulation, amplitude-modulation

I've been trying to learn VHDL recently and came across the following tutorial for an ASK modulator: https://surf-vhdl.com/implement-digital-ask-modulator-vhdl/

I tried writing a testbench for this modulator so that I can see it generate a modulated output but I am not getting anything from the output port of the dut. Here are my assumptions:

- `i_meta_sym` represents the 4 possible messages I can use from: `00`, `01`, `10` and `11`
- I can run two processes concurrently, one to generate clock signal, and another to change `i_meta_sym`
- I have used 32 clock cycles for changing between the message symbols (640ns)

Here is the result of my simulation for reference.

[image: Simulation result]

and my testbench code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity tb_modulator_ask_simple is
--  Port ( );
end tb_modulator_ask_simple;

architecture arch of tb_modulator_ask_simple is
    constant T : time := 20 ns;

    signal i_clk : std_logic; -- input
    signal i_rstb : std_logic; -- input
    signal i_sync_reset : std_logic; -- input
    signal i_fcw : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- input
    signal i_start_phase : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- input
    signal i_meta_sym : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); -- input
    signal o_molulator : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0); -- output


begin

    dut: entity work.modulator_ask_simple port map (
        i_clk => i_clk,
        i_rstb => i_rstb,
        i_sync_reset => i_sync_reset,
        i_fcw => i_fcw,
        i_start_phase => i_start_phase,
        i_meta_sym => i_meta_sym,
        o_molulator => o_molulator
    );
    
    i_rstb <= '1';
    i_sync_reset <= '0';
    i_start_phase <= (others => '0');
    i_fcw <= (others => '1');

    -- continuous clock
    process
    begin
        i_clk <= '0';
        wait for T/2;
        i_clk <= '1';
        wait for T/2;
    end process;
    
    process
    begin
        i_meta_sym <= "00";
        wait for 640ns;
        i_meta_sym <= "01";
        wait for 640ns;
        i_meta_sym <= "10";
        wait for 640ns;
        i_meta_sym <= "11";
        wait for 640ns;
    end process;


end arch;
```

Additionally, I couldn't work out how to connect the carrier wave from the `dds_sine` source so that I can also see what it (carrier) looks like during simulation.

Answer (score 1):

The rstb is a low active asynchronous reset signal, but you do not set it to 0 in your testbench at any time. So the DUT stays in state undefined, as all storing elements in the DUT remain at value 'X'. So instead of `i_rstb <= '1';` use `i_rstb <= '0', '1' after 1 ns;`